# Hash a password using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hash

I got a java class mapped to the database using Hibernate. This java class which i'm talking about contains a password which I store into the database. Due to security problem I need to hash the password before inserting it into the the database. Of course I need to verify the password inserted by the user with the hashed one. Is there a solution? Can someone help me?

Above you find the java class i'm talking about:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="utente")
public class User {

    //other code not important

    @Column(name="password", length = 256, nullable = false)
    private String password;
```

And that's what I do in the main:

```
    User user = new User();
    user.setPassword("password");
```

As you can see i'm setting a password not hashed so this is very bad from security point of view.

Comment: You said you need to hash the password, so why don't you make a hash function to do it eg `String md5_hash (String originalPassword)`, then you can `user.setPassword(md5_hash("password"))`

Comment: I think yours is a good approach, I was a little confused and I didn't think about this option. Thank you man

Comment: Please don't hash you passwords with md5 as  @Rocherlee suggested. Use proper methods such as bcrypt, scrypt, PBKDF2 with a high work factor.

Comment: @ArtjomB. What's the difference? I mean why should I need these methods instead of md5 which apperantly is doing his job fine?

Comment: md5 is really easy to brute force, because it is fast. If you deliberately use a slow function such as scrypt, you're hindering a potential attacker to get the passwords of your users and use them on other sites where your users also have accounts.